# PostgreSQL How to insert many record with one Insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a table, that all other columns have the same values, only one difference, this column is result from another select statement.

I need somethings like

```
INSERT INTO my_table (orgid, status, userid )
    VALUES(12393, true, SELECT u.userid FROM user u)
```

I can use a loop statement with many insert statement inside, but i want something more easy, 1 sqlQuery and dont use of functions :-?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
INSERT INTO my_table (orgid, status, userid )
SELECT 12393, true, u.userid FROM user u
```